# busybox format date

Tags: linux, date, text-formatting, busybox

I got a command which works perfectly on linux

```
date -d @$(git log -1 --format=%at) '+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S'
```

and now I'm trying to do the same formatting with busybox (v1.31.1), but it always fails with the following error :

> invalid date '1591877098'

Comment: What version of busybox are you using? how exactly does it fail?

Comment: @steeldriver BusyBox v1.31.1,  invalid date '1591877098'

Comment: Are you sure you didn't omit the leading `@`?

Comment: How does your command fail? Please add its exact output to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you forgot the `@`. If busybox date didn't support that format you'd get:

```
invalid date '@1591877098'
```

Not:

> ```
> invalid date '1591877098'
> ```

busybox `date` has been supporting `date -d @epochtime` since version 1.17.0 in 2010 (even though that's not advertised in the help message; see [commit](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/commit/?id=5f94346f7387cb5e33cf202dd3306f062bb22052)).

You forgot the quotes around `$(...)` though.

Should be:

```
date -d "@$(git log -1 --format=%at)" +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S
```

`%Y-%m-%d` can also be simplified to `%F`.

busybox `date` contrary to GNU `date` supports specifying the input format with `-D` (since 1.10.0, 2006, [commit](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/commit/?id=c5789a6e234c1ddec204cf65f319babb04ca6a47); though that support can be excluded at build time) in addition to the output format, so you can also do:

```
date -D %s -d "$(git log -1 --format=%at)" +%F_%H-%M-%S
```

Answer (score 0):

`date` help from [the busybox docs](https://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html):

```
date [OPTIONS] [+FMT] [TIME]

Display time (using +FMT), or set time

Options:

        [-s] TIME       Set time to TIME
        -u              Work in UTC (don't convert to local time)
        -R              Output RFC-822 compliant date string
        -I[SPEC]        Output ISO-8601 compliant date string
                        SPEC='date' (default) for date only,
                        'hours', 'minutes', or 'seconds' for date and
                        time to the indicated precision
        -r FILE         Display last modification time of FILE
        -d TIME         Display TIME, not 'now'
        -D FMT          Use FMT for -d TIME conversion
Recognized TIME formats:

        hh:mm[:ss]
        [YYYY.]MM.DD-hh:mm[:ss]
        YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm[:ss]
        [[[[[YY]YY]MM]DD]hh]mm[.ss]
```

So, epoch seconds are not a valid input time format.

Does `%ai` or `%aI` not give you close enough to what you need?:

```
$ git help log
...
               %at
                   author date, UNIX timestamp

               %ai
                   author date, ISO 8601-like format

               %aI
                   author date, strict ISO 8601 format
```

Comment: « epoch seconds are not a valid input time format. ». Yet, it is: I just got a correct result with BusyBox v1.24.1.